# linear equation $x^TA =b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do you solve the following linear equation: $x^TA = b$?

Does a solution exist, and is it unique? I know how to solve $Ax = b$, but what about $x^TA = b$?

Thanks

Comment: Just transpose both sides and it fits teh form you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take transpose.

$$A^Tx=b^T$$

Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: nice, if $A$ is nonsigular, does the $A^T$ still not singular? Thanks

Comment: $$\det(A) = \det(A^T)$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The following discussion pertains to the case $A$ invertible:

If you start with the equation

$x^TA = b, \tag{1}$

you can simply right multiply by $A^{-1}$:

$x^T =  x^T I = x^T(AA^{-1}) = (x^TA)A^{-1} = bA^{-1}; \tag{2}$

this works of course because $b$ is a row-vector.

We could of course also first take the transpose of (1):

$A^Tx = (x^TA)^T = b^T, \tag{3}$

and then left multiply by $(A^T)^{-1}$:

$x = Ix = ((A^T)^{-1}A^T)x = (A^T)^{-1}(A^Tx) = (A^T)^{-1}b^T. \tag{4}$

We can compare/validate the solution(s) by taking the transpose of (2):

$x = (x^T)^T = (bA^{-1})^T = (A^{-1})^Tb^T; \tag{5}$

(4) and (5) will evidently agree if

$(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T; \tag{6}$

but since

$A^{-1}A = I, \tag{7}$

we have

$A^T(A^{-1})^T = I^T = I, \tag{8}$

thus

$(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}; \tag{9}$

hence (4) and (5) agree.

So you need to know how to compute matrix inverses for $A$ and $A^T$, a standard problem.

One can of course apply other methods to (1), (3), such as Gaussian elimination etc.  But here we see *why* the results will agree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.